# Multi Machine setup rostopic list works but echo won't

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to subscribe to a topic on a remote machine from my base machine.When I run rostopic list it works on both systems but when I try rostopic echo for a topic it won't work.
My base machine ip -192.168.1.5 (dhcp)
remote machine ip - 192.168.1.10 (static)
they are connected to the same router and they both have export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.5:11311/
on both machine's bashrc files. And I have ROS_IP=192.168.1.5 on the base and ROS_IP=192.168.1.10  on the remote's bashrc file.When I run ping IP_ADDRESS it works both ways base-remote and remote-base. I ran roscore on the base and ran a publisher on the remote. rostopic list works on both machines but rostopic echo SOME-TOPIC won't work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266083/multi-machine-setup-rostopic-list-works-but-echo-won%27t/) by [kalvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/30679/kalvik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your ROS_IP isn't set correctly. On each machine, make sure it's set to the IP address of that machine.

`rostopic list` uses the ROS_MASTER_URI to talk to the ROS master and get the list of topics.  `rostopic echo` uses the ROS_MASTER_URI to look up the publisher and then contacts that publisher based on its ROS_IP (or ROS_HOSTNAME).

I gave a talk about troubleshooting network issues at ROSCon 2013 if you'd like a more in-depth overview: [video](https://vimeo.com/67806888) and [slides](https://roscon.ros.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Networking-for-ROS-Users.pdf).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/30679/kalvik/) on 2017-07-11**:
That's what I did. The base has the ip 192.168.1.5 and that's what ROS_IP is and the remote has 192.168.1.10.Didn't work.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-07-11**:
Can you `rosnode ping` the publishing node?

**Comment by [kalvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/30679/kalvik/) on 2017-07-11**:
kalvik@kalvik:~$ rosnode ping -c 4 mavros
rosnode: node is [/mavros]
pinging /mavros with a timeout of 3.0s
xmlrpc reply from http://192.168.1.18:36689/    time=4.885912ms
xmlrpc reply from http://192.168.1.18:36689/    time=3.579855ms
xmlrpc reply from http://192.168.1.18:36689/    time=2.745152ms
xmlrpc re

**Comment by [kalvik](https://answers.ros.org/users/30679/kalvik/) on 2017-07-11**:
I watched your video I used all the tools you explained and looks like everything is fine. So I ran a talker.py on the remote and used echo on the base. And it works fine I was able to see the data. But when I use rqt I get not monitored on every topic including talker.py's chatter topic.